# i am try my code but this error always showing me

Tags: reactjs, react-native, metro-bundler

Error: Requiring module "node_modules\react-native-reanimated\src\Animated.js", which threw an exception: Error: Reanimated 2
failed to create a worklet, maybe you forgot to add Reanimated's babel plugin?
ERROR  Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered. This can happen if:

- Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.

Comment: Have you tried adding the react-native-reanimated plugin to your babel config file as the error suggests?

Answer (score 1):

do not forget to add code below to your `babel.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
  ...
  plugins: [
      ...
      'react-native-reanimated/plugin',
  ],
```

};